# SQL group by and keep only those groups that include given value of column

Tags: sql, select, group-by, having

I have a `songs` table, a `lyrics` table and a `tags` table. A song may have multiple lyrics (or none), and each lyric has exactly one tag. So, in the `lyrics` table I have two foreign keys, `song_id` and `tag_id`, both linking to a record in the respective tables.

I would like to select all songs that **don't** have a **given** tag. For example, given the following view (the three tables are `INNER JOIN`ed):

```
song_id | lyric_id | tag_id | tag_value
---------------------------------------
1       | 1        | 1      | 'pop'
1       | 2        | 2      | 'hip-hop'
2       | 3        | 1      | 'pop'
```

given the 'hip-hop' tag, I need to retrieve the second song, since it has no linked lyric that has a linked tag with the 'hip-hop' value.

If I were to give the 'pop' tag, no songs would be retrieved, since both songs have a lyric that has the 'pop' tag linked.

How can I build such a query, in the most optimal way? I was thinking of grouping by `song_id`, then doing a `HAVING(tag_value != 'hip-hop')`, but unfortunately this isn't how `HAVING` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic usecase for the `[not] exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   songs s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   lyrics l
                   JOIN   tags t ON l.tag_id = t.id
                   WHERE  l.song_id = s.id AND 
                          t.tag_value = 'hip-hop') -- or any other tag
```